# A problem involving vector addition

Tags: vectors

The problem: Let ABCDEF a regular hexagon whose center is at M in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Show that :
$$ \overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{OE} + \overrightarrow{OB} + \overrightarrow{OC} + \overrightarrow{OD} + \overrightarrow{OF} = 6 \overrightarrow{OM} $$

Comment: Missing $\overrightarrow{OE}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit that

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry we have
$$
\overrightarrow{MA}
+
\overrightarrow{MB}
+
\overrightarrow{MC}
+
\overrightarrow{MD}
+
\overrightarrow{ME}
+
\overrightarrow{MF}
= 
0
$$
hence by summing the equations
\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{OA}&=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MA}\\[4pt]
\overrightarrow{OB}&=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MB}\\[4pt]
\overrightarrow{OC}&=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MC}\\[4pt]
\overrightarrow{OD}&=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MD}\\[4pt]
\overrightarrow{OE}&=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{ME}\\[4pt]
\overrightarrow{OF}&=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MF}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
we get
$$
\overrightarrow{OA}
+
\overrightarrow{OB}
+
\overrightarrow{OC}
+
\overrightarrow{OD}
+
\overrightarrow{OE}
+
\overrightarrow{OF}
= 
6 \overrightarrow{OM}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{OB} + \overrightarrow{OC} + \overrightarrow{OD}+\overrightarrow{OE} + \overrightarrow{OF} =  $$
$$ =(\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MA}) + (\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MB}) +(\overrightarrow{OM} +\overrightarrow{MC}) + (\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MD})+(\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{ME})+(\overrightarrow{OM} + \overrightarrow{MF}) = 6\overrightarrow{OM}+(\overrightarrow{MA}+\overrightarrow{MB}+\overrightarrow{MC}+\overrightarrow{MD}+\overrightarrow{ME}+\overrightarrow{MF}) $$

and it easy to see that
$$(\overrightarrow{MA}+\overrightarrow{MB}+\overrightarrow{MC}+\overrightarrow{MD}+\overrightarrow{ME}+\overrightarrow{MF})=0$$